# Access_token manipulation in e2e using protractor

Tags: authentication, automation, protractor, access-token, e2e-testing

I am new to e2e test automation. I am trying to access the **access_token** that if access token is issued, the app should be direct to specified URL, otherwise it should navigate to Login page. In `beforeAll()` function I have used this above mentioned condition but its not working i.e. even if token isn't issued, `if` condition returns true. Anyone have any idea how can we handle this? 
 `if(browser.executeScript("window.localStorage.access_token")!==undefined)` does the same work when it is changed to `if(browser.executeScript("window.localStorage.access_token"))`

```js
beforeAll(()=>{
    login = new LoginPage();
    addRoom = new AddRoomClass();
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            addRoom.navigateTo().then(()=>{
                
        if(browser.executeScript("window.localStorage.access_token")!==undefined){
            console.log(browser.executeScript("window.localStorage.access_token"));
            console.log('authenticated user');
            resolve();
        }
        else{
            return new Promise((resolve)=>{
                login.navigateTo().then(()=>{
                    login.getEmailInput().sendKeys('someone@gmail.com');
                    login.getPasswordInput().sendKeys('password');
                    login.getLoginButton().click().then(()=>{
                        setTimeout(()=>{
                            expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('organization').then(()=>{
                                resolve();
                                    });
                                },40000);
                            });
                        });
                    }).then(()=>{
                        resolve();  
                    });
                }  
            });
        },6000)
    });    
});
```

Code snippet is attached.

Comment: I would recommend you to set up a debugger with VS or webstorm for such things, and run code line by line to understand which one goes the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

shot in a dark... your code that you evaluate in browser's console is missing `return` like this:

```
browser.executeScript("return window.localStorage.access_token")
```